# How to sort a PHP nested associative array by one field then by another

Tags: php, usort

I have a nested associative array representing list of activities that each has fields start date and end date. Each field is represented as number of hours.

```
eg.
$activities = array();
$activities[] = array('start'=>10, 'end'=>20);
$activities[] = array('start'=>20, 'end'=>30);
```

We can sort $activities by key 'start' by

```
usort($activities, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['start'] - $b['start'];
});
```

And similarly for key 'end'.

What I'm looking for is... I want to order $activities by 'start' THEN BY 'end', and NOT sorted independently.

I've tried...

```
usort($activities, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['start'] - $b['start'];
});
usort($activities, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['end'] - $b['end'];
});
```

And of course this is WRONG since each usort UNDO's the one before it. I want to sort by 'start' THEN BY 'end'.

Here's some code to clarify my problem.

```
$activities = array();

$activities[] = array('start'=>1, 'end'=>2);
$activities[] = array('start'=>2, 'end'=>1);

usort($activities, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['start'] - $b['start'];
});

print_r($activities);
print('<br><br><br>');

usort($activities, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['end'] - $b['end'];
});

print_r($activities);
```

The result I want is

```
[start] => 1 [end] => 2
[start] => 2 [end] => 1
```

But in reality, the second usort UNDO's the first usort so it returns...

```
[start] => 2 [end] => 1
[start] => 1 [end] => 2
```

I want to order by 'start' THEN BY 'end', first usort affecting the second usort.

Comment: You don’t want to _sort_ twice, you want to sort once, but comparing items by applying _both_ sort criteria. If they are not equal by the first criterion, _then_ you have to check the second one next.

Answer (score 0):

Is this correct? Sort by 'start' then by 'end'...

```
$activities = array();

$activities[] = array('start'=>1, 'end'=>2);
$activities[] = array('start'=>2, 'end'=>1);

usort($activities, function($a, $b) {
   if ($a['start'] != $b['start']) {
      return $a['start'] <=> $b['start'];
   }

   return $a['end'] <=> $b['end'];
});

print_r($activities);
```

Comment: Yes, this Answer is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant when using the zero coalescing operator is

```
usort($activities, function($a, $b) {
   return $a['start'] <=> $b['start'] ?? $a['end'] <=> $b['end'];
});
```